# Help me guesstimate the loads I can apply to a little PE block welded to a PE wall

Tags: mechanical-engineering, welds, polyethylene

I want to mount some equipment into a [polyethylene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene) (PE) shaft. I can't bolt or drill directly into the walls, but the supplier of the shaft can weld little PE blocks onto the wall: 50x50x50 mm, with bolts pressed into the blocks.

I have about 30kg worth of piping and valves etc, most of the weight will be borne by the ground actually but I need an additional attachment point higher up. My idea was to have two of these blockse mounted on the walls, with a steel rail between them paralell to a section of pipe to attach the pipe via one or two hangers. The shaft is 1 m across, the horizontal rail will be about 0,8m. I will have shear on the blocks but no moment. The wall thickness of the shaft is at least 10mm.

At this point I don't need exact structural calculations, I need to know if this is feasible so i can leave it to the contructor to figure out, or if I need to spend more brainpower on the issue.

I understand there are plate welds and butt welds in the PE world? In either case, how much load can expect one my little blocks to bear?

Comment: Polyethylene   ... I'll add a link.

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words. I can't begin to visualise what you are talking about from your verbal description.

Comment: next time I'm near a scanner ...

Comment: Any update on this? Or is the time long past?

Comment: The times long past.